# powershell Copy File

Tags: powershell

Need some help with this script.

I have a web.config file that I need to copy recursive to 100's of folders and sub folders, but only if that folder contains ASPX files.

Comment: Where did you stop? To get the directory tree? To check if a directory contains aspx files? To copy the web.config to another location? In short: **what did you try?**

Comment: I've tried this but I'm can't figure out how to validate if aspx files exist.

$source="C:\scripts"
$destination="C:\WWW\EM_Webserver"

get-childitem -recurse -path $source -include 'web.config' | foreach {
$dir = $destination + (split-path $_.DirectoryName -NoQualifier)
New-Item $dir -itemtype directory -force
copy-item $_-destination $dir
} is there an easier way to do what I have??

Comment: @Unreal1959 you can use the Test-Path cmdlet. It accept a wildcard like *.aspx

Comment: never used that command would you mind showing me how to use it... thank you

Comment: Inside the loop: if (!(Test-Path $path)) { your stuff here }. Where $path is (split-path $_.DirectoryName -NoQualifier) with "\*.aspx" appended

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, but replace c:\rootfolder with your own folder path. Also, you will need to update the reference to the web.config file.

```
$FoldersToCopyTo = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\rootfolder -Recurse | ? { $_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] };

foreach ($Folder in $FoldersToCopyTo) {
    if (Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder.FullName -Filter *.aspxx) {
        Write-Host -Object 'copying item', $folder.fullname; 
        Copy-Item -Path c:\web.config -Destination ($folder.FullName);
    }
}
```